# JAXB Content not Instantiating

Tags: java, jaxb

Ok, I am at a loss.  I am having a Null pointer on this line:

```
    JAXBContext             context         = JAXBContext.newInstance( X3D.class );
```

And here is the output error thing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.checkOverrideProperties(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.prim.esaa.gui.x3d.MyXmlWriter.myWriteFile(MyXmlWriter.java:159)
    at com.prim.esaa.gui.x3d.MyXmlWriter.myWrite(MyXmlWriter.java:199)
    at com.prim.esaa.gui.x3d.Sim3DAnimator.writeXMLoutput(Sim3DAnimator.java:266)
    at com.prim.esaa.gui.x3d.Sim3DAnimator.initModels(Sim3DAnimator.java:212)
    at com.prim.esaa.gui.x3d.Sim3DAnimator.main(Sim3DAnimator.java:141)
```

I realize that not all the code is there and I can add more but if I understand correctly, this command setups stuff and is not at all dependent on any of my other variables.  And it was working and then just stopped.  I don't know why.

It says over and over again "Unknown Source" but I include the path and class X3D so that it should be fine.

Thanks.

Comment: What does X3D look like? Is it annotated properly?

Comment: The X3D file is empty.  The X3D class file looks fine.  And I instantiate in another file and pass that X3D created variable into this function later used when marshalling.  But on this line, if I understand correctly, it is just setting things up and fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try another version of JAXB, look http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-860